# Was Ahsoka Tano ever granted citizenship in the Galactic Republic?

Tags: star-wars

Ahsoka hails from a non-Republic planet, but she (through the Jedi) becomes a commander in the Republic army and otherwise seems to make a life in the Republic (specifically Coruscant).

In the US, any legal immigrant who joins the military is eligible for citizenship subject to certain conditions.

Did Ahsoka ever receive a Republic citizenship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently so. She refers to herself as such in [Clone Wars: *Shattered*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shattered) (S07E11)

> **Yoda:** *A great service to the Republic, you have done.*
>
> **Ahsoka:** *I did my duty as a citizen.*
>
> **Yoda:** *Not as a Jedi.*
>
> **Ahsoka:** *No. Not yet.*

Comment: The Star Wars Fandom wiki says: "The planet [Shili] was a long-time member of the Galactic Republic and Togrutas had been in the Jedi Order since its earliest years."

Comment: @moonman239 - That's in the 'Legends' category. What does it say in the 'Canon' one?